# Erro de "EACCES" ao utilizar o Cordova no OS X

Tags: apache-cordova, osx

De repente, ao acionar o comando "cordova run android", recebo o seguinte log

```
 MBP-de-Rodolfo:cordova rop$ cordova run android
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
throw err;
^
```

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/rop/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
>       You don't have access to this file.

Já tentei alterar permissões das pastas e dos arquivos, mas sempre que o faço, ao repetir o comando, aparece outro arquivo com erro de `EACCESS` (normalmente dentro da pasta do projeto Cordova).

Também tentei deletar o arquivo `insight-cordova.json`. Com isso consegui executar alguns comandos como o `platform add`, mas ao reiniciar computador o problema volta.

**Observação:** Consigo executar os comandos tranquilamente com o `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

O que voce pode tentar é mudar a forma como o terminal se loga quando ele é aberto, estava com esse problema no inicio e fiz essa alteração  e funcionou, sem problemas.

Por padrao ele se loga com o bash, mas alterando essa opção voce consegue executar os comandos basicos do cordova sem a opção sudo, confere nas preferencias no terminal.

Outra conferencia é se o ambiente cordova esta configurado de forma exata com todas as dependencias necessarias!

**node -v
gulp -v
cordova info**

Confere esses comandos e verifica o retorno do temrinal!