# Erro ao checar a versão do Apache Cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, ubuntu

Quando eu vou checar a versão do Apache Cordova no Ubuntu aparece a mensagem abaixo.

> ```
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/henrique/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
> You don't have access to this file.
> ```

Como eu resolvo?

Comment: Relacionado: [**Erro de “EACCES” ao utilizar o Cordova no OS X**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135950)

Comment: Tente esse comando: `sudo chown -R henrique /home/henrique/.config/configstore/`

Comment: Consertou o problema, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve alterar o proprietário dos arquivos do diretório:

```
# Se estiver usando distribuições Linux
/home/NOME_DO_USUARIO/.config/configstore/

# Se estiver utilizando Mac
/Users/NOME_DO_USUARIO/.config/configstore/
```

Basta executar o seguinte comendo no terminal:

```
# Se estiver usando distribuições Linux
sudo chown -R NOME_DO_USUARIO /home/NOME_DO_USUARIO/.config/configstore/

# Se estiver utilizando Mac
sudo chown -R NOME_DO_USUARIO /Users/NOME_DO_USUARIO/.config/configstore/
```

#### Explicação

- *sudo*: Indica que o comando será executado pelo **root**.
- *chown*: Altera o proprietário de um diretório ou arquivo.
- *-R*: Esse parâmetro indica que a alteração será de forma recursiva.
- *NOME_DO_USUARIO*: Altere para o nome do seu usuário.